# iOS BLE writing data not working in background

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm running my iOS device as a BLE central and I've followed various advice to make sure bluetooth is still running in the background. I know this to be the case because I am able to receive bluetooth messages while my app is in the background.  However, when I try to write in the background nothing happens.  Writing in the foreground using the same code works just fine. Is there some small print I've missed about writing over BLE in the background?!

When I receive a bluetooth message I create a notification which goes out to my Apple Watch which is all working fine in the background. When I press the "Lock now" button on the notification I want to send a bluetooth message but for some reason it's not sending.  userRequestLock works perfectly fine if I call it from a button or something when the app is in the foreground.

Code for responding to "lock now" press (in AppDelegate.m):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler     {

if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"LOCK"]) {
    NSLog(@"You pressed lock.");

    ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc userRequestLock];

}
```

}

userRequestLock (in my view controller):

```
-(void)userRequestLock{
NSLog(@"Lock Requested");
UInt8 buf[1] = {0x6C};
NSData *d = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:buf length:1];
[ble write:d];
```

}

I'm getting "You pressed lock" and "Lock requested" printed out so I know userRequestLock is being called.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: What is the `ble` object?  How is it initialised?  You are creating a new instance of the view controller, so potentially `ble` is nil

Comment: Ah OK that's probably my problem then.  ble is initialised in the view controller so it must be nil.  I'm fairly new to app developing - would you say the solution would be to put add the ble initialisation code to AppDelegate.m? Or is there some way to save ble outside of the view controller such that I can access it from AppDelegate?

Comment: Often you will have a singleton object to manage things like bluetooth

Comment: I actually just got this working using notification center so thanks for the hint!